# How to convert this Java/Soap Methods in REST Methods?

Tags: java, rest, soap, methods

**How to convert this Java Methods in REST Methods?**

```
Employee[ ] getAllEmployees()

Employee getEmployee(String id)

Employ (Employee employee)

modify_Employee (Employee employee, String id)
```

**I think the solution is**

```
GET /api/employee

GET /api/employee/{id}

POST/api/employee/{employee}

PUT /api/employee/{id}/{employee}
```

**but Im not sure**

Comment: Have you tried your solution, did it work? You should try to solve your problem, and in case you encounter a problem, then you could ask for help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need two URI's, each with implementations for two methods.

- `/api/employees`

  - use `POST` to create a new employee. This method accepts a document containing a single employee serialised as JSON / XML / ...
  - use `GET` to retrieve all employees. Returns appropriately formatted document containing a list of employee representations, or (perhaps) a list of links to the individual employees. Possibly paginated. You could also choose to allow the URI to accept query parameters to allow filtering / searching.
- `/api/employees/{id}`

  - use `GET` to retrieve an individual employee
  - use `PUT` to modify the existing employee
  - both methods work with the same document representation format

Note: it's a common convention to use plural forms for URI path elements which represent a 'group' - hence `employees` rather than `employee`. But the choice is entirely yours.